# How can we specify keytab based login information for multiple user principals while using Java GSS-API with Kerberos?

Tags: java, kerberos, gssapi

I am using Java GSS-API with Kerberos for secure Authentication. I want to connect to two different KDC Servers from single Client program to access multiple services. For that I am using configuration file krb5.conf as shown below:

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = HOST1
udp_preference_limit = 1
[realms]
HOST1 = {
    kdc = host1:88
}
HOST2 = {
    kdc = host2:88
}
```

For login, I am using keytab based login with configuration as shown below:

```
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab=user.keytab
  principal="user1@LOCALHOST"
  storeKey=true;
};

com.sun.security.jgss.accept {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab=service.keytab
  principal="service1@LOCALHOST"
  storeKey=true;
};
```

This configuration requires principle name to be mentioned as a part of configuration file. Now the problem is that we can specify only one principle name in the configuration, but I want to access multiple services requiring login for multiple principal names. How can I specify login information for multiple user principals?

Comment: You are using the default name for each section (and an obsolete name, by the way). You could start by using explicit names, like Kafka -- i.e. `Client { ... ; } ; Server { ... ; } ;` and invoking the conf sections by name.

Comment: Then you will need to manage different "Subject"s explicitly, and specify fior each action which "Subject" you "DoAs". Have fun.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for the response. If we use custom names for those configuration sections, how can we use them through gss-api. Can you please provide example code?